# Spring Boot With Async Dynamo Client. Is it advantageous?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb, asynchttpclient

I am new to Asynchronous programming.
I am using Spring boot for my application and using DynamoDB as my DB.
All my calls to DB are synchronous and blocking and hence leading to performance issues.
I know that spring boot spawns multiple threads to serve requests. Is it right if I change my calls to asynchronous for dynamodb here? Also, a note, the version of dynamo i am using is not truly asynchronous, it only uses the executor service.

Comment: Why don't you switch and do a load test for yourself?

Comment: I need to develop the application quickly. That's why I am asking.

Comment: If you replace blocking IO with NIO, you are bound to see a performance boost. Also, I am not sure what you mean by "not truly async". An async task is something that runs in a background thread. That thread can very well be from an executor service.